# Can a newton polynomial provide more accuracy than natural cubic splines in some cases?

Tags: interpolation, numerical-calculus

My assignment is to interpolate the sin function using 10 points of the function with 6 decimal correct places with polynomials and splines. The polynomial interpolation gave me at worst 4 correct decimal places, while the splines gave me at worst 2 correct decimal places. Can that happen given a specific set of points or is my implementation wrong?

Here are the points:

```
  x(1, 1) = 0;
  x(2, 1) = 0.203056;
  x(3, 1) = 0.267584;
  x(4, 1) = 0.379246;
  x(5, 1) = 0.527854;
  x(6, 1) = 0.713500;
  x(7, 1) = 0.916740;
  x(8, 1) = 1.087621; 
  x(9, 1) = 1.274532;
  x(10, 1) = 1.570796;
  
  y(1, 1) = 0;
  y(2, 1) = 0.201663;
  y(3, 1) = 0.264402;
  y(4, 1) = 0.370220;
  y(5, 1) = 0.503681;
  y(6, 1) = 0.654484;
  y(7, 1) = 0.793622;
  y(8, 1) = 0.885524;
  y(9, 1) = 0.956434;
  y(10, 1) = 1;
```

Comment: The accuracy usually depends on the nodes we choose. We need more context to answer this question.

Comment: You are right i added the points i used in the post. As you can guess from the distribution of the points accuracy is better towards 0 than towards pi/2. Can that specific set of points excuse the difference between the polynomial and the spline interpolation?

Comment: Splines and Tchebycheff-interpolation avoid the so-called Runge-phenomenon that can occur if equidistributed notes are used and the degree of the interpolation poylnomial is high. The resulting polynomial can then be heavily oscillating , but in this case , the function in the desired interval seems to behave well enough for a good accuracy. You can try Tchebycheff and compare the results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original function is a polynomial of degree 4 or higher, then polynomial interpolation will give you zero approximation error, but cubic spline interpolation will give a non-zero error. So, in this particular case, the polynomial method will certainly work better.

Polynomial interpolation isn't as bad as many people say, and you shouldn't expect that it will always behave poorly. You'll get oscillation problems if you do interpolation using equally spaced nodes, but not if you use Chebyshev nodes. There's a good discussion of these matters in Trefethen's book, [Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Approximation_Theory_and_Approximation_P.html?id=h80N5JHm-u4C&redir_esc=y).